# sql studio express 2005 lost sa password issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a problem, I'm using windows 7 with MS SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 although I've lost my administrator/ sa password.  Is there a command I can use to reset the password, without the old one?

I can login using windows authenication.

many thanks,
James

Comment: This question really belongs on SuperUser

Comment: would a reinstall of sql express 2005 do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login to the SQL Server computer as the Administrator of that computer. Open Query Analyzer and connect to SQL Server using Windows NT authentication. Run sp_password as shown below to reset the sa password:

```
sp_password @new = 'will_never_forget_again', @loginame = 'sa'
```

**EDIT:**

This is unexpected, as you were able to get in to detach a db, so you must
have some privileges. The message you got:
... is a response to the `sp_password` command.  So when you say you tried to
reconnect with 'sa', can you tell us how you did that?

Also, when using the **SQLCMD** tool, you have to type **GO** to execute a command:

```
SP_PASSWORD @NEW = 'my_password', @loginame = 'sa'
GO
```

Then you need to exit before you try to reconnect.

Try getting in again, and seeing who you are. So after connecting:

```
C:\sqlcmd -E  -d master
```

Please run this:

```
SELECT suser_sname(), user_name()
GO
```

Also, run this after you obtain your user name and enter your new password per my original answer:

```
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE
GO
```

Comment: Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: I used 'sa' as an example. You need to change it to whatever your actual login name is and set the password to whatever you want your new password to be.

Comment: I cannot create a database or create new logins because I dont have permission.  Will installing SQL Express resolve this issue?

Comment: I have tried the SP_PASSWORD within the new query dialog.  I cannot attach or do anything..  I've create a database through MS Visual Studio although I want to create a database within SQL Express, instead of attaching it within Visual Studio..  When logging into SQL express I can get in using windows authenication although I can only see system databases.  When trying to create a new database I get permission denied on 'master'.

Comment: running select suser_sname(),.. within a new query window I am only a 'guest' :(

Comment: ok, sorry..  I reinstalled this: http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express-down.aspx (Install Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition) and it allowed me to set the sa password.  I made a new instance of SQLExpress1.

Comment: nice, so are you all set to go then?

Answer (score 0):

In the object explorer, go to Security-> Logins and click on preferences for the "sa"-account. There you can reset the password

Comment: Using the preferences I'll need the old password?

Comment: Be sure to run MS SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 as Administrator. Then you can just type and retype the new password in the Password and Confirm Password fields

Answer (score 0):

Because you can login using your windows authentication then it's pretty easy.
what you need is just

1. login to your management studio,
2. on the tree view, expand   "security" folder,   and also expand the
   "Logins" folder,
3. right click on "sa"
4. change the password. done